# How to make limitations for constructor values in java?

Tags: java

What is the right way in java to limit constructor values?

I want to make sure that its NOT possible to create objects using MyConstructor with the parameter int value > 5

example: (pseudo code)

```
public MyConstructor(value){
   if(value < 5){
       this.value = value;
   } 
}
```

Comment: 1: that code won't compile 2: use an enum for compile-time safety

Comment: Although the code is not valid Java code, I understand your question.  An enum or a specialized type may help.  Also, do you want the limitation at compile time or run time?

Comment: Explain precisely what you actually want to achieve. What is the actual class, what is the actual parameter for, what does it represent, and why it must be less than 5. At the moment, your question is much too vague to provide good advice.

Comment: we normally throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if `value >= 5`

Comment: You could [throw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) when an invalid value is passed.

Comment: I want to create objects using a constructor and pass a parameter BUT I want that its not possible to pass a parameter which is >5 as this would not make any sence in my program. So I'm looking for a proper way to do this. I mean I can do this in diffrent ways but I want to know the "best" one.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443406/how-do-i-insert-a-precondition-in-a-java-class-method-or-constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSR-303 Bean Validation API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html):

```
@Max(4)
int value
```

> JSR-303 allows you to define declarative validation constraints against such properties:
>
> ```
> public class PersonForm {
>
> @NotNull
> @Size(max=64)
> private String name;
>
> @Min(0)
> private int age;
> ```

Specifically [@Max](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html)

> The value of the field or property must be an integer value lower than or equal to the number in the value element.
>
> ```
> @Max(10)
> int quantity;
> ```

Comment: That does not prevent you from constructing such objects though, I don't think that's what OP means. (plus it's a bit convoluted for doing such a basic thing)